# ARM scatter file symbols not defined?

Tags: compiler-errors, arm, makefile

In my scatter file, I have a memory region named TCM_COPY,

In my C file, i am trying to extern the region_name like,

extern unsigned int Image$$TCM_COPY$$Base.

But when I compile that C file, the ARM compiler generates an error;

L6218E: Undefined symbol Image$$TCM_COPY$$Base.

I am wonder why I can't import that region symbol from my scatter file??

Answer (score 1):

Can you past your scatter file?

I tried to define a new Execution Region with an empty buffer, following http://www.keil.com/support/docs/3629.htm:

In my scatter file:

```
LR_IROM_TEST 0x0802F000 0x00000100  {
  BUFFER 0x0802F000  EMPTY 0x10 {}
}
```

In my c file:

```
extern unsigned int Image$$BUFFER$$Base;
```

It is possible to use BUFFER to access to your region (if size buffer = size LR_IROM_TEST).
It works for me.

This link may be helpful:
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armlink/armlink_pge1362065956104.htm